# How to check if I'm running ASP.NET Core app on EC2 instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I'm running my ASP.NET core application on AWS EC2 Instance.

I want to know if it is running on AWS or my local machine on the application start.

For example, we have `env.IsDevelopment()` method to see if it is developer matching or not; maybe there is a similar way for AWS?

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //Something here?
}
```

I tried to use

```
Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
```

but it didn't help

Comment: `IsDevelopment` works by reading the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable. If it's `Development`, then it's a Development environment. That variable can have any value, but ASP.NET Core recognizes the predefined ones, `Production` , `Staging` and `Development`. The default is `Production`

Comment: Just set the value you want in the environment variable when you create the VM, and read its contents in your `Startup` file. Even the settings files are loaded based on that value. There's nothing magic about `appsettings.Production.json`. The WebHost loads `appsettings.{env}.json` where `env` is the value of the environment. You can do the same yourself, to create file names based on various criteria, eg the OS name

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a solution that works for me:

```cs
var awsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AWS_EXECUTION_ENV");
if (awsSection.Exists() && awsSection.Value == "AWS_ECS_EC2")
{
   //Code which should be running on AWS only
}
```

The suggested ideas in the comment were also good, but they didn't fit me. I have several virtual machines, and in the future, there will be more. So, I don't want to add environment variables each time. I wanted to have a solution that works for each EC2 instance, and in fact, this is the variable that always exists.